# How to include Keyboard in SafeArea in .NET MAUI

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, keyboard, maui

I read in this thread, that the default for iOS is, that the Keyboard is included in the Safe Area [SwiftUI - Why does the keyboard pushes my view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456168/swiftui-why-does-the-keyboard-pushes-my-view/65456215#65456215)

It appears in MAUI, this default behaviour is disabled since the keyboard covers entries by default. How can I access the iOS-specific API from MAUI to enable this default behaviour?

Comment: So you want your View to push the safe area into the view is it?

Comment: You can see these two issues on GitHub: [Enhancement SafeArea Thickness for ContentPage](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2342) | [iOS Keyboard Scrolling with Star-sized grid row](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18354).